# Is there any difference between the following two sentences?

Tags: meaning, grammar, syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

I read the first sentence on likes.com. I wonder if there is any difference  between the following two sentences:

> 1. We all have them, but your chin *could be telling* you more than you know about you and everybody else.
> 2. We all have them, but your chin *could tell* you more than you know about you and everybody else.

Comment: The second is not well-formed, that is ungrammatical.

Comment: It was "could tell you "

Comment: The sentences are both fine, and mean (roughly) the same thing. But the first "be telling you" structure is very common in internet and magazine articles. It's a nod to a fairly recognizable structure.

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence seems strange, because *tell* is not used in the sense of *speaking up* here. If you *do* use it literally, you could see a sentence like

> Your friend could tell you more about your girlfriend than you know.

Which means that *if* your friend would tell you something about your girlfriend, he would tell you things you didn't know about her.

Your chin doesn't talk. But it *can* tell you something - maybe because of its shape. *If* it tells you something, it is doing so the whole time; your chin doesn't sit down for a chat with you, it conveys any message it has continuously.

> We all have them, but your chin could be telling you more than you know about you and everybody else.

So this sentence means that possibly, your chin is conveying a message about you (and other people?) that you didn't know about.